# Tor Browser do not start

Tags: tor, tor-browser

I tried to start Tor Browser using the icon from the unzipped folder, but nothing happened. 
Same with the line command :

```
./start-tor-browser.desktop
bash: start-tor-browser.desktop: command not found
```

How can I run the Tor Browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First ensure that the script has execute permission

```
sudo chmod +x start-tor-browser
```

you misstype the command, from inside the unzipped directory run the command

```
./start-tor-browser
```

or click on the `start-tor-browser` this shows you dialogue choose `run`

[image]

Comment: nothing happens

Comment: It doesn't show me this dialog

Comment: what is the output of `ls -l start-tor-browser`

Comment: check the edit above

Comment: -rwx------ 1 user3 user3 12735 ian  1  2000 start-tor-browser

Comment: Does not work at all! the problem root is something other!